# Tomcat 9 web socket examples

Tags: java, tomcat, java-websocket

I am tring to compile (javac) the Tomcat examples specifically the
`echo endpoint.java` examples `/WEB-INF/classes` folder has an
echoendpoint.class file.  I must assume it came precompiled in the
zip file for tomcat9 since I cant seem to get it to compile.  It can't
find the package `javax.websocket`.

```
error: package javax.websocket does not exist
```

I can find all kinds of Oracle documentation on the javax websocket
 package but cant figure out where to download the jar file(s. I am
using jdk 1.8.0_161

I am an old school programmer and really don't like all these tools
 that try to do things for me (eclipse, maven).  I like to know
 exactly what is going on and be in control. So I am doing everything
 from the command line and editing with sublime3 my environment
 variables show:

```
LLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData APPDATA=C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming CATALINA_BASE=D:\tomcat9\apache-tomcat-9.0.7
CATALINA_HOME=D:\tomcat9\apache-tomcat-9.0.7
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-NMIG0RS ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Owner JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-NMIG0RS NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=12
OneDrive=C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program
Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\java_ee_sdk-7u3-web\glassfish4\bin;C:\Program
Files\Microsoft VS
Code\bin;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

I tried adding D:\tomcat9\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\lib to the class path on
 the javac command thinking it might pick up tomcat-websocket.jar or
 websocket-api.jar but that didnt help either.  so I have a multipart
 question:

1. where can I get the required Jar files?
2. why doesn't Oracle include ALL their jars in their jdk download? I seems to me that they should include at least all the Javax jars.
3. why doesn't apache include a `.bat` file for building all their examples?

Comment: 1. javax packages are part of the jre afaik, 2. Idk, they decided not to? 3. look at 2. Consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Adding a directory to the `CLASSPATH` only adds the `.class` files that may be found there and in subdirectories (with a particular package structure). If you want to add `websocket-api.jar` to the `CLASSPATH` then you'll have to do it like this:

```
C:> javac -cp D:\tomcat9\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\lib\websocket.jar myClass.java
```

Tools like Eclipse and Maven already understand these dependencies and can take away all of the typing that you'll ed up doing if you need to include 20, 30, or 100 different libraries on which your project depends.

To answer your questions directly:

> 1. Where can I get the required JAR files?

The one you are looking for in this particular case actually comes bundled with Tomcat, but you can also [get them from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/apis-139520.html), too. The problem is that the Websocket API is a part of the Java EE APIs and if you didn't know that, you might not know that's what you need to download.

> 2. Why doesn't Oracle include ALL their jars in their JDK download?

Because there are *huge* numbers of APIs and not everybody needs all of them. When you install Microsoft's Visual Studio, do you want it to install the Visual COBAL++ pre-processor, the Fortran# compiler, and the Microsoft Bob Simulator as well? Probably not.

> 3. Why doesn't apache include a `.bat` file for building all their examples?

Because it's insanely inconvenient when real, useful build tools exist. The Tomcat project uses Apache Ant to build everything, including the `examples` web application. You are much better off using Ant than you are building from a .bat file. Yes, it's complicated. It's complicated because building Tomcat is complicated. Building the `examples` web application less so, but being able to issue a `<javac>` task that understands where the dependent JAR files are is much better than having to re-roll the whole `javac` command every time something changes.

If you want to compile the `examples` web application conveniently, you should download Apache Ant and run this command:

```
C:> ant compile-webapp-examples
```

If you make changes to the web application, you'll get your changes compiled, too.

It's worth pointing-out that this isn't something that is inherently a part of some Java-based conspiracy to confuse "old school programmers". Before working (almost entirely) in Java, I've had a long history in C and other languages. Anything past a single-source-file C project practically *requires* a `makefile`, and many of the projects I was involved with also had lots of other steps in a build-from-source activity. Things like running a compiler-compiler (lex/yacc, etc.) before the C compiler is invoked, etc. Also, most C compilers only compile a single file at a time. So if you have 100 source files, you need 100 lines in a naive build-script. Then, you need the link step which might actually be many steps. If you need 2, 30, or 100 different dependent libraries, you will need to go and acquire them from their respective sources and then mention them all in the linking step (the C compiler doesn't include `libssl` or `libwhatever` or, sometimes, even `libc`). So it's not straightforward, either.

Comment: the comment size limit just saved everyone from dealing with my soapbox rant  on "modern" programming tools I guess I will get that posted somewhere else and just provide a link in some future comment.

Comment: @LatitiaLee Usually a simple "get off my lawn" gets the point across.